# Looking for a source and the authenticity of the story of 'Omar ibn al-Khattab and the secret drunkards

Tags: source-identification, authenticity, reference-request

There's a story I've at least once saying that during his Caliphate 'Omar ibn al-Khattab unmasked some people drinking alcohol in secrete -at night- when he wanted accused them for committing a sin they answered we have committed a single sin while you've committed three:

- You didn't ask for permission before entering our house while Allah says:

  > O you who have believed, do not enter houses other than your own houses until you ascertain welcome and greet their inhabitants. That is best for you; perhaps you will be reminded. ([24:27](http://legacy.quran.com/24/27))
- You didn't come from the door, while Allah says:

  > ... And enter houses from their doors. And fear Allah that you may succeed. ([2:189](http://legacy.quran.com/2/189))
- and finally you spied us, while Allah says:

  > O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other.  ... ([49:12](http://legacy.quran.com/49/12))

Where or in which book does this story appear is there any source for it?

Is this story authentic?

Comment: A number of sources are listed here, with a judgement that its source is not trusted. https://www.ahlalhdeeth.com/vb/showthread.php?t=167859

Answer (score 1):

Al Sunnan Al Kubrah - Al Baihaqi book 8 page 333
The book is written in Arabic I could not find a translation, here it is anyway: [http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/الكتب/1761_السنن-الكبرى-البيهقي-ج-٨/الصفحة_333](http://shiaonlinelibrary.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A8/1761_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%86%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%83%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%89-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%82%D9%8A-%D8%AC-%D9%A8/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%81%D8%AD%D8%A9_333)

Comment: If it was in al-Mustadrak then finding it in al-Bayhaqis work doesn't surprise me as he was al-Hakims student. But what surprises me is the source of your link. Actually this only tangentially answers my question.